# Would it be possible to get xpath location from value?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape this section of the website with Selenium on Python 3.7, there is nothing unique about it, there are many sections of the website with the exact same style.

```
  <tr><td style="black 2px solid" colspan="1"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Total</td><td style="color: blue" valign="top">1,233</td><td style="color: green" valign="top"> (86.35%) </td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="1">&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

The only thing unique is the value being 'Total', I need to scrape the td after that which is '1,233'. 
When using: find elements by xpath I use this xpath:

`('.//td[text()="Total"]')`

I have been playing around with paths and with no luck.

**Would it be possible to get xpath location from value?**

Thank you :-)

Comment: looks like you forgot to state the website url. Read this post and learn [how to ask a Q](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this one on [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value `1,233` use either of the following xpath.

```
//td[text()='Total']/following-sibling::td[1]
```

OR

```
//tr[.//td[text()='Total']]/td[2]
```

---

In selenium using python

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[.//td[text()='Total']]/td[2]").text)
```

Or

```
print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[text()='Total']/following-sibling::td[1]").text)
```

---

For best practice induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`()

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//td[text()='Total']/following-sibling::td[1]"))).text)
```

You need to import below libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @AshwinMelwani :Glad that helps.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the usage of WebDriverWait until.

y = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(d)[0].text

Would I be able to use it when finding the value, like in the situation above?

Comment: @AshwinMelwani : I would suggest please go through that link https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Will do. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
//td[text()="Total"]/following-sibling::td[1]
```

You can test it here: https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html

Comment: Thank you so much! Appreciate that awesome resource you sent through. Bookmarked it.